# Error: 'gisq.game.mdate' isn't in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g, group-by

The link to the table is given here :-
http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/The_JOIN_operation

Question No :- 11 of this

For every match involving 'POL', show the matchid, date and the number of goals scored.

When My Query is :-

```
SELECT matchid, mdate, count(player)
FROM game join goal on id = matchid
WHERE (team1 = 'POL' or team2 = 'POL')
GROUP BY matchid
```

**Error in this case.**

But when my query is :-

```
SELECT matchid, mdate, count(player)
FROM game join goal on id = matchid
WHERE (team1 = 'POL' or team2 = 'POL')
GROUP BY matchid, mdate
```

**My answer is right.**

***Issue :- I have read somewhere on stack overflow that group by function needs everything written in the select statement.
But why count(player) isn't included in GROUP BY clause?***

Comment: "I have read somewhere on stack overflow that ..." - I'd suggest you to read official documentation. (Forum) discussions are *great*, I use them ... huh, *from time immemorial*, but not everything someone somewhere says is true. Now, either you forgot what has exactly being said, or that *someone* person said it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

When you GROUP BY, what it means to the SQL is that you want the unique combinations  of the fields listed in the GROUP BY.

And then you can select those fields without having to use them an aggregate function like COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG, ...

But that rule also works in reverse.

For example this query.

```
SELECT x, y, MAX(z)
FROM foo
GROUP BY x
```

The query wants the unique x according the GROUP BY.
But what y should it show for that x?  The one with value 'bar1' or maybe 'bar2'?

The `MAX(z)` doesn't have to be in the GROUP BY because it's an aggregation function.
The returned value of such function depends even on what fields are in the GROUP BY.

It would know for sure what to show for y if  this was the SQL

```
SELECT x, MIN(y), AVG(z)
FROM foo
GROUP BY x
```

So that's why at least in most databases both x and y have to be in the GROUP BY if you select them without using an aggregate function.  Which is a SQL92 standard.

MySql can be more tollerant about that rule.
Which is mostly fine if the coder knows what them are doing. But could also lead to misleading results.

But that test site obviously doesn't allow their MySql to accept missing fields in the GROUP BY.

Comment: "But what y should it show for that x" , yes you're right when it comes to avg or count functions but with max and min, y can be simply the value corresponding  to this min(z) or max(z)

Comment: ooh i just forgot that the max can be attributed to two values of y...

Answer (score 1):

> why count(player) isn't included in GROUP BY clause?

Becasue `count(player)` is *aggregate function* it doesn't to add in `group by`

When you use *aggregate function* you need to add non-aggregate columns in `GROUP BY` clause.

In this example `count` is aggregate function when you use it.you need to add `matchid` and `mdate` columns in `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT matchid, mdate, count(player)
FROM game join goal on id = matchid
WHERE (team1 = 'POL' or team2 = 'POL')
GROUP BY matchid, mdate
```

If you don't specify the non-aggregate columns column name in `GROUP BY` clause , aggregate function its unknown to the SQL engine which value it should return for that kind of column.

Comment: It isn't clear at all, what you want to say. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Venkatesh  I add the more explain on the bottom.